# Calculating expected value for a fair coin

Tags: probability

A coin is thrown until the second time a head comes up or until three tails in a row occur. Find the expected number of times the coin was thrown. [image: what I have so far]

I started by listing some cases (hopefully all) and decided probability of getting 2 heads is 9/12 and getting 3 tails is 3/12..I know to find the expected value I need to multiply the outcome by the probability and then take the sum but I’m just unsure where to go from here. Advice please!

Do I want to calculate the probability based on the number of tosses? Like succeed in 2 tosses has a 1/12 chance, 3 tosses 2/12, 4 tosses 5/12, 5 tosses 2/12 and 6 tossss 1/12 to calculate expected value?

Comment: The total number of tosses can not be very big.  I guess you can have $TTHTT$ as the longest unsuccessful string.  Thus the total number is at most $6$.  With that it mind, it shouldn't be hard to list all possible strings with confidence.

Comment: Do I want to calculate the probability based on the number of tosses? Like succeed in 2 tosses has a 1/12 chance, 3 tosses 2/12, 4 tosses 5/12, 5 tosses 2/12 and 6 tossss 1/12 to calculate expected value?

Comment: You're missing at least THH.

Comment: Anyone see any others missing?

Comment: To be sure I would list them by length.  After all the sequence must either end in $H$ or $TTT$.  For short sequences total enumeration is easy, for slightly longer ones it helps to fix the end and work backwards.

Comment: case 10 = case12.  There are 13 cases so THH is missing and also THTTT.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to redefine the problem to the probabilistically equivalent one where a coin is tossed six times(all the outcomes we are interested in is covered by this experiment) and we assign our random variable the value two if the sequence of length six starts with HH, the number three if it starts with any of the sequences of length three that you've written and so on. This covers all sequences of length six, which are $2^6=64$.

Now, HH covers $1/4$ of these $64$ cases(which is also evident from the fact that throwing two heads in a row has probability $1/4$) so the random variable has value $2$ with probability $1/4$. The value is $3$ with probability $3/8$, $4$ with probability $4/16=1/4$, $5$ with probability $3/32$ and $6$ with probability $2/64=1/32$. Note that the probabilities sum up to one, which is because they cover all possible outcomes of six tosses.